# Trouble capturing image on Google Glass

Tags: android, camera, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm having trouble capturing an image and saving it to external storage on Google Glass. I have the following code.

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, null);

    String imagePath = getPhotoPath();

    _imagePath = imagePath;
    File imageFile = new File(_imagePath);

    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, ACTION_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

And the code for getPhotoPath()

```
    private String getPhotoPath(){

    String photoPath = null;

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

        long captureTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/TOTAL_" + captureTime + ".jpg";
    }       

    return photoPath;
}
```

I've verified that _imagePath is not null but when I attempt to do the following in onActivityResult()

```
    File imageFile = new File(_imagePath);

    if(!imageFile.exists()){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "sendPhoto: FILE DOES NOT EXIST, imagePath=" + _imagePath);
    }
```

The file doesn't exist. I can verify that it doesn't exist on the storage by looking in the File Explorer at the Google Glass device in Eclipse.

I have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest for the project but something is still off.

A potentially related logcat message:

```
01-06 16:28:15.067: E/CachedFilesManager(634): Failed to change mode on file /mnt/sdcard/thumbnail_cache/t_thumb_20140106_162814_113.jpg
01-06 16:28:15.067: E/CachedFilesManager(634): java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
01-06 16:28:15.067: E/CachedFilesManager(634):  at com.google.glass.fs.Filesystem.changeMode(Native Method)
01-06 16:28:15.067: E/CachedFilesManager(634):  at com.google.glass.util.CachedFilesManager.save(CachedFilesManager.java:433)
01-06 16:28:15.067: E/CachedFilesManager(634):  at com.google.glass.camera.CameraUtils.saveThumbnailToCachedFiles(CameraUtils.java:76)
01-06 16:28:15.067: E/CachedFilesManager(634):  at com.google.glass.camera.ApiTakePictureActivity$1.doInBackground(ApiTakePictureActivity.java:110)
01-06 16:28:15.067: E/CachedFilesManager(634):  at com.google.glass.camera.ApiTakePictureActivity$1.doInBackground(ApiTakePictureActivity.java:105)
01-06 16:28:15.067: E/CachedFilesManager(634):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:273)
01-06 16:28:15.067: E/CachedFilesManager(634):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-06 16:28:15.067: E/CachedFilesManager(634):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-06 16:28:15.067: E/CachedFilesManager(634):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-06 16:28:15.067: E/CachedFilesManager(634):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-06 16:28:15.067: E/CachedFilesManager(634):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Any idea what's going on? Is writing to the Glass storage just not allowed at all? Doesn't seem likely but I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator or on hardware?

Comment: No emulator, I have Google Glass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glass does not support the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` intent extra for specifying the path to the final image file. Instead, see the example in the [GDK Camera Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/media-camera/camera) to see how to retrieve the path to the saved image file and use a `FileObserver` to wait for it to be written out.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I should've looked more thoroughly through the documentation.